# How to generate a pkcs7 signature envelope using pkcs11interop

Tags: signature, pkcs#7, pkcs#11, envelope

To prevent the token password dialog, I usually use pkcs11interop to login to the usbkey and do data signature use capi or some COM+ control in C#.

But now I have a new usbkey. When I do signature the first time it still display the login dialog. This key's pkcs11 dll does not implement function C_SignUpdate, so when I try to do signature use SunPkcs11 and BouncyCastle in Java it throw a exception:

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String configName = "d:\\javakey_My.cfg";
        String PIN = "123456";
        Provider prv = new SunPKCS11(configName);
        Security.addProvider(prv);
        KeyStore credentials = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
        char[] pin = PIN.toCharArray();
        credentials.load(null, pin);

        Key key = (PrivateKey) credentials.getKey("My Cert ID", null);
        Certificate[] chain = credentials
                .getCertificateChain("My Cert ID");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) chain[0];
        Store certs = new JcaCertStore(Arrays.asList(chain));
        // set up the generator
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder()
                .setProvider("SunPKCS11-MyKey").build("SHA1withRSA",
                        (PrivateKey) key, cert));
        gen.addCertificates(certs);
        // create the signed-data object
        CMSTypedData data = new CMSProcessableByteArray(
                "Hello World!".getBytes());
        CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(data, false);
    }
```

```html
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED
 at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineUpdate(P11Signature.java:436)
 at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineUpdate(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.Signature.update(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.Signature.update(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder$SignatureOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
 at Tryit.main(Tryit.java:108)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_FUNCTION_NOT_SUPPORTED
 at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_SignUpdate(Native Method)
 at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineUpdate(P11Signature.java:430)
 ... 7 more
```

Is there any way to do a P7 signature use this key? by .Net or Java, without login dialog.

Comment: Code snippet you have provided is kinda useless because it only shows that your PKCS#11 library does not support C_SignUpdate function which seems to be irrelevant to your main problem - dialog shown during the signature creation. Could you please update the question with the code that reproduces this problem?